# How to rebuild a broken state?

Tags: economy, political-system, corruption

Afghanistan (CPI index of 172/174) or Somalia (CPI Index of 174/174). These countries are the most corrupt countries in the world (according to the 2014 [Corruption Perspectives Index](http://www.transparency.org/cpi2014/results)).

According to CPI, politicians are corrupt, security is very low, most of people are illiterate, natural resources are not used and organized correctly, the people who are educated often emigrate to other countries.

What are the options to rebuild a broken state?

Comment: At this point Somalia isn't a country at all in a meaningful sense. Some parts of it (mainly Somaliland) have organised themselves, perhaps not exactly in the way external actors would hope for but somewhat effectively. Of course this hasn't turned the area into another Sweden but conditions seem to be better than a decade or two ago.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild a country means to understand how deep is the problem the country has, what are the resources available to exploit and help the economy, which most of times, is so broken, the country even has enough force to pay public officials. The OP mentioned just 2 countries but there are [more examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_States_Index#2015): Mali, Congo, Iraq, Haiti, Niger and more.

Give just one solution is fall in the International Monetary Fund's solution to everyone: *cut public spending, invest in infrastructure, attract foreign investments*, in short **austerity**, even when they don't even have nothing to spend. Why do I say this? the [IMF gave the same recipe](https://clg.portalxm.com/library/keytext.cfm?keytext_id=33) to get out of the crisis to Argentina, Greece and Cyprus and nothing happen until today.

Having said, there some commons measures these countries could take, for example:

1. **Increase development assistance and policy advice to economic
   production, especially in agriculture**. The country needs productive
   base and more when it comes about food. This aid could help the
   country to develop a small productive market, fight against poverty,
   and develop a self-income to the population. There's lot of debate
   of how poverty should be faced but this is the most important phase,
   **in my own opinion**.
2. **Support the creation and security of the legal system, to promote
   the production and trade**. The protection of basic human rights, the
   access to justice and the creation of basic organizations to enhance
   the trade and enforce contract will help to develop accessibility
   which is going to grow over time. The expansion can cost lots of
   time but without a organized system, the financing won't be
   attractive to investors.
3. *"We don't aid, we need trade"*. In my country, the international
   community often offer cheap international loans to develop roads,
   grow the public system and other good goals. The main problem is, we
   don't need more assistance. We want build an international export
   route to put our products in the foreign market and in return,
   receive more technical assistance based in our need, not "Spam
   projects" to help the poor. (This is completely empirical evidence)
4. **No liberal projects in the early days**. Ha Joong in the book "[23 Things you Didn't
   know about Capitalism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1501266306)", explain that developing countries aren't
   benefited from this doctrine. To live and have benefits from the
   liberalisation, a country should have a strong financial system,
   stronger judicial system, healthy bank system. Historically, most
   developed countries today were in the early days a closed economic
   system. The best example of this hypothesis is the international
   crisis. Yes, of course they can't close the borders, but promoting
   the intern market will help to develop a strong market in order to
   compete in the globalized market, especially when we talk about
   heavy industry.

---

PS: This is a personal list, the orders could changes of priority according to your view. I don't take the education system because you can't teach people with empties stomaches. First food and trading, then education.

PS 2:To go deeper in the subject, I recommend the paper: ["Fixing failed states"](http://scholarship.law.berkeley.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2761&context=facpubs)

Comment: Your last bullet point, do you mean economic or political liberalism?

Comment: I'm referring both but the approach is about economic liberalism, specifically the [neoliberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoliberalism)

Answer (score -2):

Different states require different methodologies in order to be rebuilt. For now, I will only talk about the two primary countries mentioned in the question, Afghanistan and Somalia.

Firstly, Afghanistan is a country that has been tarnished by wars over the past few decades. However, based from my understanding from a Time's article, the chaos is mostly in the south, and that the north is relatively peaceful. The north is also the part of Afghanistan with more resources. From my point of view, the way to rebuilding Afghanistan is to first setting up a coalition government with the Taliban. If not, the Taliban will not hesitate to plunge the country to greater troubles. However, the members of the Taliban in this government should be the less extremist figures. additionally, the head of state should be one that is reliable enough to continue reforms, one that should have similar traits to Iran's current president Hassan Rouhani. Subsequently, a state enterprise should be started. This enterprise will be in charge of mining in Afghanistan. This would enable more people to be hired, primarily those from the north. The growth is prosperity would then flow towards the other parts of the country. More people would gain access to education. This would mean that the government would have to be as incorruptible as possible. To do so would mean having to set up an anti-corruption task force comprising people who have previously emigrated from Afghanistan and corruption officers from less corrupted areas like Singapore and Scandinavia. This is while the US and NATO maintains a minor presence in the country. Sure, this method might not be able to achieve all targets and goals, but at least it set the country on the road towards being rebuilt.

Secondly, Somalia is a country that contains little natural reserves, scarce food and water. It also suffers from some military conflicts. To rebuild Somalia, the militants would need to be flushed out from the country, and the people would need to educated. The people can be educated only when livelihoods are ensured. This means that new methods of supplying food and water would need to be innovated to tailor to Somalia's needs. Jobs would also need to be created. This can be started when educated people who have emigrated from Somalia return and pioneer such changes. Once such changes begin to take root, an anti-corruption task force similar to the one suggested for Afghanistan can be started. This would ensure that the growth in economy either is passed on to the country's reserves or to it's people.

Thus, to rebuild these countries, multi-fronted and multi-pronged strategies have to be employed.

Comment: Taliban are extremists, there aren't less extreme figures to deal with.

Comment: I agree that the Taliban are extremists. However, I was speaking in relative of the Taliban. Within the Taliban itself, surely there are figures that are less extreme and figures that are more extreme. What I was referring to are the less extreme members within the Taliban itself whom are still considered extreme in the mainstream. With the present outlook, there is no choice to include these less extreme Taliban figures.

Comment: There are low to none prospects that the Taliban would agree to take part in a coalition government.

Comment: That is true. However, I cannot foresee a situation where Afghanistan can be rebuilt when there is a government totally run by the Taliban or a continued violence led by the Taliban. One can only hope so....

Comment: Top-down solutions usually don't work. If the people themselves don't support a solution, it will fail.